# Derivation of expression for mean number of toss to get r heads

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am independently working through Grimmet and Welsh's "Probability: an introduction" and am having some difficulty solving a question in chapter 2, namely 2.6.2.

Problem statement: "Each toss of a coin results in heads with probability p(>0). If $m(r)$ is the mean number of tosses up to and including the $r^{th}$ head, show that
$ m(r) = p[1+ m(r-1)] + (1-p)[1+m(r)]$. Def: $q = 1-p$

Solution attempt:
I interpret the mean as a special case of the expectation value. Defining according to a geometric distribution, the probability of the number of tosses, $k$, required to get $r$ heads is $P(X=k) = p^rq^{k-r}$. Rearranging the expression given in the problem statement, we can get

$$
m(r) - m(r-1) = \frac{p+q}{p}
$$

So basically I interpret this as saying that the difference between the expectation value of $r$ heads and $r-1$ heads needs to be $\frac{p+q}{p}$. Then (cutting out some algebra),

$$
E_r(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^rq^{k-r} = q\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^r\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}
$$

and

$$
E_{r-1}(X) = \frac{1}{pq}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^rq^{k-r} = \frac{q}{pq}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^r\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}
$$

and the difference becomes:

$$
\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^r(q-\frac{q}{pq})
$$

I can't get this to reduce to the problem's request, so I'm missing something somewhere. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: All that recursion says is:  "consider the first toss, it is either $H$ (prob. $p$) or $T$ (prob $q$).  If it is $H$ then you have spent one toss and now you need to get $r-1$ Heads.  If it is $T$ then you have spent one toss but you still need to get $r$ Heads."   Phrased (slightly) differently "every path to $r$ Heads is either $H$ followed by a path to $r-1$ Heads or it is $T$ followed by a path to $r$ Heads."

Comment: I think I see what you mean. So, the first toss becomes a partition, and we can then use something like the partition theorem of expectation values (mean here) to derive the recursion?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\quad$

Comment: So then the partition becomes $E(X|heads)p +E(X|tails)q $. The expectation value for the first term is really $1+m(r-1)$, since the first toss occured, and then we need $m(r-1)$ more heads, and similarly for the second term, giving the desired relation. Thanks so much! If you form your comment into an answer, I will accept it